# Angular tree structure with 2 different list populating from nested rxjs subscription

Tags: angular, tree, rxjs, angular-material

In Angular 7 I have two observable which is getting data from the server; Observables gives the following lists:

```
    productgroup = [{"id":"1","groupname":"gr1"},{"id":"2","groupname":"gr2"}];
    products = [{"id":"1","productname":"COMPUTER","productgroup":"gr2",....},{"id":"2","productname":"ACCESSORIES","productgroup":"gr1",....}]
```

I have to make a tree data structure to create a menu with an angular material tree like the following:

```
    [
        {
            "id":1,
            "name": "gr1",
            "children": [
                {"id":"1","productname":"COMPUTER","productgroup":"gr2",....},
                {"id":"2","productname":"ACCESSORIES","productgroup":"gr1",....}
            ]
        }
        {
        }
    ]
```

The code i have tried is as following --

```
 this.productGroupService.getAll().pipe(switchMap((allgroup: any) => {
          var flag = 0;
          this.groups = []; // array to hold group or parent data
          allgroup.map(element => {
            this.finalarr = []; // fial array 
            console.log(element.id);

            this.productService.getbygroup(element.id)// for each group getting product data list
            .pipe(map((data) => {
              this.productInGroup[flag] = []; // array to hold children data
              this.groups.push(element);
              data.map((dval)=>{
                this.productInGroup[flag].push({productname: dval["productname"], id: String(dval["id"])});
              })
              flag++;

            })
            ).subscribe((data) => {
              if(allgroup.length == flag){
                //console.log(this.groups);
                var flag2 = 0;
                this.groups.map(()=>{
                  var obj = {groupname: this.groups[flag2].groupname,id:this.groups[flag2].id,
                    products:this.productInGroup[flag2]}; // joining child and parent data into single object
                  this.finalarr.push(obj);
                  flag2++;
                  if(flag2 == this.groups.length){
                    this.datasource = this.finalarr;
                    console.log(this.datasource);
                  }
                })
              }
            })
          });
      })).subscribe()
```

At first I am looping over productgroup list and creating a parent array.
Then for each group, I am getting data from the server by subscription and creating a child array. Then making an object with that array and pushing it to the final array.

The code is working for small dataset. But I am not happy with this solution
as it iterates through all products for all groups nxm times.

I know it would have been much easier if the table in the database were associated via foreign key and a flat list but I don't have control over that.

Any help or suggestion is appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By introducing state your solution has become very complex.

Try this

```
  const productGroup$ = this.productGroupService.getAll();

  productGroup$.pipe(
  mergeMap((productGroupArray) => from(productGroupArray)),
  concatMap(
    (productGroupItem) => this.productService.getbygroup(productGroupItem.id).pipe(
    map((product) => {
      let json = {};
      json['id'] = productGroupItem.id;
      json['name'] = productGroupItem.groupname;
      json['children'] = product;
      return json;
    })
  )),
  toArray()
).subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

Inside subscribe you will get the array directly.

Comment: Althrough its nxm iteration but your code is much cleaner. I wasn't familier with conCatmap. I have tested your code and it works like a charm. Just changed toArray() method because its a typo.Also i don't need it as i am getting value directly inside subscription. Thanks

Comment: Why won't you need toArray(), because in your question the final response is something like an array, right? Also If the solution worked you can mark it as accepted. Glad to help.